# How to filter MultiIndex dataframe based on 1st level max values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe `s`:

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
          [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2,]]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(8), index=index)

first  second
bar    1        -0.493897
       2        -0.274826
baz    1        -0.337298
       2        -0.564097
foo    1        -1.545826
       2         0.159494
qux    3        -0.876819
       2         0.780388
dtype: float64
```

I would like to convert it to:

```
first  second
bar    2        -0.274826
baz    2        -0.564097
foo    2         0.159494
qux    3        -0.876819
dtype: float64
```

By taking the `max` `second` of every `first`.

I tried doing `s.groupby(level=1).apply(max)`, but this returns:

```
second
1   -0.337298
2    0.780388
dtype: float64
```

Clearly my attempt returns the max for each group in `second`, instead of the `max` `second` for each `first`.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sort_values` + `tail`

```
s.sort_values().groupby(level=0).tail(1)
Out[33]: 
first  second
bar    2        -1.806466
baz    2        -0.776890
foo    1        -0.641193
qux    2        -0.455319
dtype: float64
```

Comment: @ScottBoston fixed thanks:-) . my head is Defunctional :-(.

Comment: Why is `foo` 1?

Comment: @Newskooler random value ... I did not using the same input like you .

Comment: @Newskooler use `np.random.seed(123)` to fix the values so you can test.

Answer (score 4):

Use `idxmax` and boolean indexing:

```
s[s.groupby(level=0).idxmax()]
```

Output:

```
first  second
bar    2         0.482328
baz    1         0.244788
foo    2         1.310233
qux    2         0.297813
dtype: float64
```